# How Grahas were made and assigned their task

Tags: vedas, vishnu, shiva, puranas

I see Chandra(lord moon) is the son of Atri and Anusuya, how he was made as graha and to rotate around earth

Lord surya is the sun of kashyapa, how was this earth before surya was born